# How to get Python Compound Interest Calculator to give the correct answer?

Tags: python, calculator

I've run into the issues of my Compound Interest Calculator giving the wrong calculation when you input the principal, compounded interest (yearly, monthly, etc..), interest rate (0.03, etc...), and the number of years.

[Previous question's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948946/final-p-1-r-n-nt-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for)

So from the previous code, I removed `p = 10000, n = 12, r = 0.08` because it would give a large number when you input different numbers. My hope was it would calculate it with the numbers inputted, but it doesn't.

```
# User must input principal, Compound rate, annual rate, and years.
P = int(input("Enter starting principle please. "))
n = int(input("Enter Compound intrest rate.(daily, monthly, quarterly, half-year, yearly) "))
r = float(input("Enter annual interest amount. (decimal) "))
t = int(input("Enter the amount of years. "))

final = P * (((1 + (r/n)) ** (n*t)))
#displays the final amount after number of years.
print ("The final amount after", t, "years is", final)
# At the moment it is displaying a very random number.

Enter starting principle please. 1000
Enter Compound intrest rate.(daily, monthly, quarterly, half-year, yearly) 1
Enter annual interest amount. (decimal) 0.01
Enter the amount of years. 1
The final amount after 1 years is 1010.0
```

The final amount should be `1000.10`. Not sure what is going on. Trying to see if there is a way to make `P, n, r` equal the number of user inputs that will result in the correct final answer.

Comment: Why should it be 1000.10? If I understand correctly, yearly compound interest rate 0.01, so 1000*(1.01)^1=1010.0. Am I missing something here?

Comment: When I run the number through a compound interest calculator to triple check the answer it gives me 1000.10.

Comment: Added an answer. Please check if this is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Based on this: 
Compound Interest Formula 
FV   =   P (1  +  r / n)^Yn, 
where P is the starting principal, r is the annual interest rate, Y is the number of years invested, and n is the number of compounding periods per year. FV is the future value, meaning the amount the principal grows to after Y years.

```
P = int(input("Enter starting principle please. "))
n = int(input("Enter number of compounding periods per year. "))
r = float(input("Enter annual interest rate. e.g. 15 for 15% "))
y = int(input("Enter the amount of years. "))

FV = P * (((1 + ((r/100.0)/n)) ** (n*y)))

print ("The final amount after", y, "years is", FV)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are entering interest in percentages, you should take care of that in your code.

```
final = P * (((1 + (r/(100.0 * n))) ** (n*t)))
```

Comment: Ahhh. didn't even think about that. Thanks, I will run it now and let you know.

Comment: It works! Thank you, been doing these projects since 6am, can't believe I missed that. Appreciate the help @ Sagar

Comment: Welcome. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. :P

Answer (score 1):

```
# name
NAME=raw_input("Enter Name= ")

# Principle amount
P =float(input("Enter Principle Amount: "))

# Rate of interest
R = float(input("Enter rate of Interest: "))

#No Of years
T = float(input("Enter No of Years= "))

#compound interest calculation
CI = P * ( 1 +  R / 100)**T

print"compound interest is {:.2f}".format(CI)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below Python code for Compound Interest:

```
p = float(input('Please enter principal amount:'))
t = float(input('Please enter number of years:'))
r = float(input('Please enter rate of interest:'))
n = float(input('Please enter number of times the interest is compounded in a year:'))
a = p*(1+(r/(100*n))**(n*t))
print('Amount compounded to: ', a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Formula to calculate compound interest annually is

A = P(1 + R/100) t

Compound Interest = A – P

Where,
A is the amount,
P is the principal amount,
R is the rate and
T is the time span

```
def compound_interest(principal, rate, time):
    Amount = principal * (pow((1 + rate / 100), time)) 
    CI = Amount - principal
    print("Compound interest is", CI) 
compound_interest(100000000, 14, 8)
```